# Where can I find the Keras configuration file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, keras

I have installed Keras on my Ubuntu machine, and would like to ask where can I find the Keras configuration file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If you have run Keras at least once, you will find the Keras
>   configuration file at:

```
~/.keras/keras.json
```

See more at http://keras.io/backend/